# Installing NLTK via terminal (sudo: pip: command not found) (Mac)

Tags: macos, command-line, installation, python, terminal.app

Mac 10.13.4

Trying to install NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/install.html)

Using command `sudo pip install -U nltk` as stated in the above resource.

Returns `sudo: pip: command not found`

What does this mean in this instance?

Why would I not use `sudo apt-get install python-nltk`?

Return for `which -a python python3` shows `/usr/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3`

Is it because I'm running 3.6 and req is 3.5? The resources notes for older versions you may have to do setuptools and pip but... something seems off to me because I have an updated Macos.

Comment: Pip was not installed on python 3.6. Perhaps the documentation should reflect that 3.6 (from python.org) needs separate pip.

Comment: `pip` is bundled with `python3.6`, you just need to call it via `python3.6 -m pip install somepkg`.

Comment: If you want to have a separate installation of `pip` (the pre-3.4 way), run `sudo easy_install3 pip` (referring to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)).